# Transactional Replication - Can it be used on a shared server?

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

Transactional Replication - Can it be used on a shared web server with MS SQL 2005 Express ?

Comment: Based on your information, yes. It may be more useful to do some research and post a specific issue, i.e. like read this, the first thing that came up for me on google: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165686(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - yes researched all that - the issue is the hosting space is SHARED ie.e I do not have access to the raw database as such

Comment: Shared means a lot of things. In your case you'll need to work out the server access and firewall constraints that your particular shared hosting space allows.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks - I have a connection string to the database and usually connect to it with a front end called SQL Maestro but in terms of setting up transactional replication I don't know how I can do this with this level of access.

Comment: If you can run SQL statements against the database, try some of the commands listed under 'using transact-sql' in this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151225.aspx. I can't give you specific instructions as I've never set it up before. There's a lotto learn about implementing transactional replication. First you need to configure a publisher to push to it, and I guess this will not be a hosted database?

Comment: The publisher is a full copy of SQL server, i'll have a read, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can but SQL Server express can only be a transactional subscriber. You will not be able to publish from it, but can publish to it.

Note that there will be some contention between SQL Server Express and a web server, so such a deployment is not scalable in the long run.